# I am getting the The method onListItemClick(ListView, View, int, long) is undefined for the type ActionBarActivity Error

Tags: java, android

**MainActivity.java:**

```
   public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private String[] mPlanetTitles;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
.....
```

and

```
.....
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        Dastan dastan = dastanha.get(position);// migim dastani ke rush kelik
                                                // shode ro beriz dakhele
                                                // "dastan"
        Intent next = new Intent(this, ShowDastan.class);
        next.putExtra("thisdastan", dastan);
        startActivity(next);// migim ke dastan ro be safhe bad befres

    }
.....
```

**Pic** : http://8pic.ir/images/d6182p5uf5npszbn2aus.jpg

**Text error** : The method onListItemClick(ListView, View, int, long) is undefined for the type ActionBarActivity

The problem arose when adding Navigation Drawer
How do I solve this problem? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will help-----

list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

```
list1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array));
```

list1.setOnItemClickListener(
        new OnItemClickListener()
        {

```
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                int position, long id) {
```

///do the operation

}

Comment: If I send my project to fix the problem you're

Comment: I'm a beginner and do not know where I copied this code

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html use this link if you don't understand you can send me your project.I will complete it.

Comment: Thank you for helping 
This is my project http://up.persianscript.ir/uploads/f310-project-plus.rar

Comment: I got your project.My I am unable to see it because of my office work.I need some time say 2-3 days.As soon as it is finished I will contact you.Here is my email-id sohambannerjee8@gmail.com.You are free to contact me.

Answer (score 1):

`onListItemClick` comes from `ListActivity`

define the `onItemClickListener` as its own variable and reference that instead.